# Laravel with LDAP

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to connect to OpenLDAP using Laravel. All I did was follow the https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v1/ tutorial. But this tutorial only connect to trial LDAP. I need to connect to my localhost openLDAP.
I'm using these .env configs:

```
LDAP_LOGGING=true
LDAP_CONNECTION=default
LDAP_HOST=127.0.0.1
LDAP_USERNAME=null
LDAP_PASSWORD=null
LDAP_PORT=10389
LDAP_BASE_DN="dc=example,dc=com"
LDAP_TIMEOUT=5
LDAP_SSL=false
LDAP_TLS=false
```

Ldap connection test comes successful. But when I try to login using UI, I get that credentials are wrong. i only have created one user so cant be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/core/v1/configuration/#username-amp-password): "To connect to your LDAP server, a username and password is required to be able to query and run operations on your server(s)."

So you need to enter a (proxy) username and password at the `LDAP_USERNAME` and `LDAP_PASSWORD` prompts in order for the application to be able to interact with the LDAP server.

My guess is that you need to enter the user DN and not the short username: `uid=username,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` or similar